# Mathematical designation of a cuboid that has one or two edges with infinite length

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Is there a mathematical designation for a cuboid that has one or two of its edges with infinite length (in essence, forming an infinite subset of the 3-D space)?

This would be some kind of 3-D strip or the band if one edge only is of infinite length and a slice if two are.

Answer (score 0):

One way to call such geometric bodies, including the original finite sided cuboid, is as "polyhedra" if they can be bounded or unbounded, and "polytopes" if they are bounded. Generally speaking, a polyhedron is the set of solutions to a system of linear equations and/or inequalities. If it's bounded then it's a polytope. For a "cuboid" you're talking about, bounded or not, you have linear inequalities given by upper and lower bounds on each axis for each bounded axis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but "polyhedron' is too generic as it designates any solid in 3D space (with flat faces). I was wondering whether there was a more specific term for 3D strips or slices.